# General solution to n-th order linear ODE

Tags: analysis

Consider the differential equation $y^{(n)}=ky$ for all appropriately-chosen $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

I was able to solve the case $n=1$ by hand and obtain $y=Ce^{kx}$ and I am aware of the solution $y=C_1e^{\sqrt{k}x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{k}x}$ for $n=2$. WolframAlpha appears to have no trouble at all solving for greater values of $n$. However, I found it somewhat difficult to identify a pattern.

How can one go about finding the general solution to this equation?

Comment: Writing "for all" followed by "appropriately chosen" is self contradictory. Either it is for all parameters or for a certain choice of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Observing the ode $y^{(n)}=ky$ we note first that is linear. Also that $y= c e^{\alpha t}$ is a potential solution because by substitution

$$
c\alpha^n e^{\alpha t}-k c e^{\alpha t}=c e^{\alpha t} (\alpha^n-k)=0\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

assuming $c\ne 0$ we have that any $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha^n=k$ is a particular solution and also that we have $n$ independent particular solutions then, as the ode is linear

$$
y=\sum_{j=1}^n c_{j}e^{\alpha_j t}
$$

where $\alpha_j$ are the distinct roots of $(1)$ is a solution and is **the** solution.